# couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

when i setup mongodb in my ubuntu , i try : ./mongo it show this error :

```
 couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js
```

so what can i do ,

thanks

Comment: How did you install it? Did you use a aptitude? Did you download the tarbal directly?

Comment: i had this error and it was because on ubuntu I didn't run `mongod` first

Answer (score 124):

- Manually remove the lockfile: `sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock`
- Run the repair script: `sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf    --repair`

Please note the following:

- You must run this command as the mongodb user. If you run it as root,
  then root will own files in /var/lib/mongodb/ that are necessary to
  run the mongodb daemon and therefore when the daemon trys to run
  later as the mongodb user, it won't have permissions to start. In
  that case you'll get this error: Unable to create / open lock file
  for lockfilepath: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission
  denied, terminating.
- On Ubuntu, you must specify the configuration file /etc/mongodb.conf
  using the -f flag. Otherwise it will look for the data files in the
  wrong place and you will see the following error: dbpath (/data/db/)
  does not exist, terminating.

Comment: how to run that as the mongodb user?

Comment: Simply add yourself to the mongodb group:
useradd -G mongodb fady
replace fady with your user name.

Comment: i run repair many times but didn't worked till i manually removed the .lock file (as you stated), its now working, but i just want to know that why manually removing .lock file work ?

Comment: The lock file is supposed to prevent mongodb from running when database is in inconsistent state to prevent data corruption and in normal cases you shouldn't remove it manually.

Comment: For more information you can refer to this page:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair

Comment: I've had to use both the information of this answer and from @boulder_ruby 's answer. This because my '/data/db/' was missing. Maybe it could be a good update for this answer to be more complete.

Comment: My mongod was not started after the repair script on Ubuntu 12.10. Had to start it manually: `sudo service mongodb start`

Comment: @fadymohamedosman if I use my mongodb user in sudo -u  I get errors of permission denied of mongod.log file modification.

Comment: `Mon Aug 22 11:28:17.919 Can't specify both --journal and --repair options.`

Comment: Why are you specifying the --journal option?

Answer (score 32):

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock   
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --repair 
sudo service mongodb start
```

Here is all, sometimes, it takes a little while to start mongo after performing these operations.

Comment: If I try ` sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --repair` here is what i get: `Mon Aug 22 11:28:17.919 Can't specify both --journal and --repair options.`

Answer (score 21):

Trying running $mongod

If you get en error such as

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.5
connecting to: test
Fri Jun  1 11:20:33 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed

hisham-agil:~ hisham$ mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=53452 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=hisham-agil.local
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.5, pdfile version 4.5
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin gamma.local 11.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:48:32 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] options: {}
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist, terminating
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 dbexit: 
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Then you've run into a basic startup error that is pretty common.

By default mongod will try to use /data/db for its database files, which in this case, does not exist.

You can't start

```
mongo
```

until you handle

```
mongod.
```

Try creating those directories and make sure they are writable by the same user that is running the mongod process.

**See similar question-- [Getting an error, "Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js" &  when trying to run mongodb on mac osx lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845092/getting-an-error-when-trying-to-run-mongodb)

Comment: you can also set the dbpath like so: mongod --dbpath ../data

Answer (score 20):

This is actually not an error... What happens here is that Mongo relies on a *daemon* in order to run the local database server, so in order to "fire up" the *mongo server* in your shell, you have to start the *mongo service* first.

For **Fedora Linux** (wich is the Distro I use) You have to run these commands:

```
1 sudo service mongod start
2 mongo
```

And there you have it! the server is going to run. Now, If you want Mongo service
to Start when the system boots then you have to run:

```
sudo chkconfig --levels 235 mongod on
```

And that's all! If you do that, now in the shell you just have to type ***mongo*** in order
to start the server but that's pretty much it, the problem is you have to start the SERVICE first and then the SERVER :)

P.S. The commands I posted might work on other linux distros as well, not just in fedora... In case not maybe you have to *tweak some words* depending on the distro you're using ;)

Comment: Same Solution applies to question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958228/mongodb-running-but-cant-connect-using-shell

Comment: So many times I get stumped and scratch my head for a long time, and finally realize: 'oh, I just have to sudo."

Comment: and for Debian/Ubuntu variants:

`sudo service mongodb start`

Answer (score 11):

I got the same problem when I tried to install mongo. I got Error as,

**Error**

```
"Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84"
```

**Solution:**

First install mongod by using:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-server
```

Then type

```
mongod --dbpath /mongo/db
```

Then

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

Then

```
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf  --repair
```

Thank You

Comment: Will this method delete the existing databases in mongo?

Answer (score 6):

You need to delete the lockfile `mongod.lock` or `/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock` on ubuntu, then you need to run `mongod.exe` or `service mongodb start` on ubuntu first, then run `mongo.exe` or `mongo` on ubuntu.

Comment: The OP is on Ubuntu, so I'm pretty sure they won't be using any `.exe` files.

Comment: I'm getting this error message, and I can't find a "mongod.lock" on my file system. Do these instructions apply to Mac OSX?

Answer (score 5):

Either your mongod is not running (check using "ps" command) or it is listening on some outside IP address and not on localhost. So  first check the process list if 'mongod' is running. If yes, check with "netstat -nap" for the related port.

Of course you can start mongod on the console manually or even look into the mongod logfile
(if there is one configured...depending on how you installed mongod).

Answer (score 5):

First you have to make sure that all the files and directories in your /var/lib/mongodb/ folder (or whichever folder dbpath points to) belong to the mongodb user and mongodb group.

```
cd /var/lib/mongodb/
sudo chown mongodb filename.*
sudo chgrp mongodb filename.*
sudo chown -R mongodb directory
sudo chgrp -R mongodb directory
```

(Replace filename and directory with their respective names)

Then you can remove the lock, repair the database and restart the daemon as other people already mentioned:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock   
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --repair 
sudo service mongodb start
```

Comment: How come there are no upvotes to this? This was the only solution, among half a dozen SO entries that I looked, that worked for me. Thank you, sir.

Comment: The command to start with the config file and force a repair is `sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --repair` on Ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 5):

First start your mongo server by

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:csv1 Admin$ mongod
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

Then open another terminal window and open shell

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:csv1 Admin$ mongo
```

Answer (score 2):

Also check that your root partition has enough space to start mongod.

```
df -h /
```

You'll see smth like this on mongod launch:

```
Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] 
Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use --smallfiles
Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] 
Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 dbexit: 
Mon Aug 12 17:02:59.159 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, try this:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d mongodb start
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be combination of $PATH and Permission issue.

Try following steps given below:

Update your $PATH variable to point to your MongoDB bin file. In my case brew install MongoDB to this folder:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/
```

In order to update your $PATH variable, do following:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/paths
```

Then, press ‘i’ to insert text in Vi and append the your MongoDB path to the end of the ‘paths’ file and restart the terminal.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/bin
```

Use ‘Esc : w q’ to save and exit from Vi editor.

Use echo to display your path variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/2.4.6/bin
```

Now try to check the Mongo version, if you get following, then you are on the right track!

```
$ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
```

Now we need to create the database directory. I used the default ‘/data/db’ location suggested in MongoDB docs. I also created a log directory to avoid any permission issues while Mongo tries to create any logs. Change ownership and that will do the job.

```
$ sudo mkdir /data/db
$ sudo mkdir /data/log
$ whoami
username
$ chown -R username /data
```

Now, we will create a default config file for MongoDB to be provided for the first time we run ‘mongod’ command. Now, I will also like to point out that ‘mongod’ will start a service, which will listen for incoming data connections. This is similar having ‘$service mysqld start’ executed.Let’s go ahead and create the config file. Please keep in mind that I have created very basic config file. However, you can add many other variables to configure MongoDB. This is the first time I am playing with MongoDB, so I just know as much as I read on MongoDB docs!I created ‘mongodb.conf’.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/mongodb.conf
```

Add following:

```
fork = true
port = 27017
quiet = true
dbpath = /data/db
logpath = /data/log/mongod.log
logappend = true
journal = true
```

Please note that the default port for MongoDB server is 27017. Use your own path for dbpath and logpath you created in Step – 5. Don’t forget to close and save the conf file.

Now we are all set to start our MongoDB service. Open two instances of Terminal.In Terminal 1, type in:

```
$ sudo mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 3516
all output going to: /data/log/mongod.log
child process started successfully, parent exiting
```

If you get above message, then know that you have successfully started your Mongod service.

Now, to connect to it, in Terminal 2 type following:

```
$mongo test
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings:
Tue Sep 3 16:55:43.527 [initandlisten]
Tue Sep 3 16:55:43.527 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
>
```

Ignore the warnings, but you are successfully connected to the ‘test’ database! Cool!

That's all. I applied this solution, when I tried to install copy of MongoDB on my Mac for the first time. See if this help you too.

For detailed post you can go here - http://arcanebytes.com/2013/09/03/mongodb-installation-on-mac-os-x/#comment-1036112094.

I hope it helps!

Cheers,
Chinmay

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @RadimKöhler, thanks for heads up. I have corrected the answer. Hope this will help someone. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem on ubuntu 12.04 by following steps:
1) sudo rm /var/log/mongodb
2) sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb
3) I removed mongo and then installed it again
4) sudo service mongodb restart

and All is Well

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu:

Just Open the terminal and enter the below command.
You just have to restart your mongoDB.

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```