# Getting an error, "Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js" &  when trying to run mongodb on mac osx lion

Tags: mongodb

I am using Mac OS X Lion and i just did a fresh install of MongoDB using macports and when i try to run mongodb for the first time i get the following error

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.5
connecting to: test
Fri Jun  1 11:20:33 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed
```

can anybody please help with this? thanks

when i run mongod i get:

```
hisham-agil:~ hisham$ mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=53452 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=hisham-agil.local
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.5, pdfile version 4.5
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin gamma.local 11.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:48:32 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_I386 i386 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] options: {}
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist, terminating
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 dbexit: 
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Fri Jun  1 11:24:47 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: @bdares: you should post that as the answer

Comment: Reading help: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist

Comment: Ohhhhh, you got attacked by the community because of the title. You need to change your title.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're running the mongo client without starting the server first.  Try running mongod first.

You'll have to specify where the mongo "workspace" is using the --dbpath switch, such as `mongod --dbpath /mongo/db`.  The specified folder should exist.

Comment: i have edited the post to show the error i get when i run mongod

Answer (score 4):

By default mongod will try to use the directory `/data/db` for the database files.

In your case that directory does not exist.

Before starting `mongod` you should create those directories and make sure they are writable by the same user that is running `mongod` process.

Answer (score 3):

I deleted `/data/db/mongod.lock` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my mac. Try,

> sudo chown -R `id -u` /data/db

Then start the daemon specifying your dbpath /data/db, as in bdares post above. This worked for me.