# exception during recovery in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I tried to recover from sudden shutdown of mongo , as written in this post by: 
[fady mohamed osman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6848840/587228), but i am experiencing some problems. Here is  the log file

My log is :

```
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3563 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=milos-desktop
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.2, pdfile version 4.5
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] git version: 514b122d308928517f5841888ceaa4246a7f18e3
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] build info: Linux bs-linux64.10gen.cc 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] options: { auth: "true", config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb1.log", repair: true }
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] recover begin
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] recover lsn: 77394770
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] recover /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._0
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] journal file version number mismatch. recover with old version of mongod, terminate cleanly, then upgrade.
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] exception during recovery
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13536 journal version number mismatch 0, terminating
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 dbexit: 
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Tue Apr 16 17:45:25 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: Did you change the MongoDB version ?

Comment: I can'r remember, how can i check if i did? How can i find out which version to use?

Comment: Is it the mongo Version is same before sudden shutdown and after recovering ? You can check the version when you connect to DB.

Comment: I cannot connect to database, i cannot even start mongodb process.

Comment: You have any previous log File, so that you can get the version of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can also happen because of unclean restarts/ shutdown as explained in the bug [SERVER-5380](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5380?focusedCommentId=107906&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-107906). Remove all the files in `/db/data/journal` (maybe different for your setup, you can confirm this in the log generated while starting the service) folder and restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs I could see that you are using 2.0.2. If the Mongo Version before the crash is different than this, you will get above error. Use the same version of Mongo to resolve the issue.