# cant start mongo db , initandlisten exception

Tags: mongodb

I try to start mongodb with mongod. This is my error message:

> I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating

So I tried to start it from my mongodb folder ( which has a folder with data , and this one has db in it) and still doesnt work. It got the same error message.

Comment: this isnt true, because if i do the steps from this post my problem isnt solved

Comment: MongoDB generally looks for a `data/db` folder in C drive if you're using Windows. If you want to give it your own folder, then 

`mongod --dbpath path/to/your/folder`

Comment: Possible Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20729155/mongod-shell-doesnt-start-data-db-doesnt-exsist

Comment: This is a better answer.. we needed to create a data/db folder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579630/i-try-to-run-mongod-server-on-ubuntu-exception-in-initandlisten-29-data-direc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB requires a data directory to store all data. MongoDB’s default data directory path is the absolute path \data\db on the drive from which you start MongoDB. Create this folder by running the following command in a Command Prompt

> md \data\db

You can specify an alternate path for data files using the --dbpath option to mongod.exe, for example

> "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data

If you are working on windows then for me the best link to follow is

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

and same for Linux and OS X given inside Installation category within this link.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are using linux
when using linux the folder /data/db is refering to the root folder.
try to run `ls /data/db`

you need to set your config file to refer to the full valid path or specify `data/db` without the first / to make it a relative path.

Comment: and where do i find this config file usually ?

Comment: if mongodb has created a config file for you then it would probably be in "/etc/mongod.conf", else you would have to create a config file, here is a link to know more on config files, https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/configuration-options/