# I try to run mongod server on ubuntu : exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating

Tags: mongodb

I try to run a mongod server and its giving a error comment it below :
i tried few comment  kill port and lock file comments not it dosent work ..

```
2016-11-14T03:52:20.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2921 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=codepanda
2016-11-14T03:52:20.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.10
2016-11-14T03:52:20.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317
2016-11-14T03:52:20.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2016-11-14T03:52:20.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-11-14T03:52:20.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-11-14T03:52:20.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-11-14T03:52:20.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2016-11-14T03:52:20.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-11-14T03:52:20.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-11-14T03:52:20.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-11-14T03:52:20.308+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2016-11-14T03:52:20.308+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the directory:

```
mkdir -p /data/db
```

Comment: Thank for your reply...
now its give this error .. i try kill to  mongod server and its rondomly generate new port ....

Comment: distmod: ubuntu1604
    2016-11-14T08:10:23.417+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2016-11-14T08:10:23.417+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2016-11-14T08:10:23.417+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
    2016-11-14T08:10:23.565+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
    2016-11-14T08:10:23.565+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

Answer (score 1):

This is because the directory '/data/db' you created is writable only by super user but you are trying to run as normal user. So, the following command 
`sudo chown -R $USER /data/db`
makes you super user. 
Now, try running
`mongod`.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB requires a data directory to store all data. MongoDB’s default data directory path is the absolute path \data\db on the drive from which you start MongoDB. Create this folder by running the following command in a Command Prompt

> md \data\db

More detailed information given here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46886272/6242317

Answer (score 1):

For new arrivals, consider that your /etc/**mongodb.conf file may be out of date**. Did you copy it from a previous installation or modify it using outdated instructions?

For example, as of Mongo 4.2 the smallfiles option is no longer recognized and MongoDB will reject the conf file and resort to defaults ( i.e. /data/db ).

The configuration file documentation is here: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/