# Cannot access data dirctory on mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is what happens after running the command `$ mongod -dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/data/db`:

> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.644+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB
>
> starting : pid=4346 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb/data/db 64-bit
> host=era-Inspiron-5559
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.644+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version
> v3.4.2
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.644+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version:
> 3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.644+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL
> version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.644+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator:
> tcmalloc
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.644+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.644+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build
> environment:
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.644+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod:
> ubuntu1604
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.644+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch:
> x86_64
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.644+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
> target_arch: x86_64
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.644+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {
> storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb/data/db" } }
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.645+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in
> initAndListen: 29 Data directory /var/lib/mongodb/data/db not found.,
> terminating
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.645+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown:
> going to close listening sockets...
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.645+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown:
> going to flush diaglog...
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.645+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
>
> 2017-02-12T14:39:18.645+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down
> with code:100

Please help.

Comment: does `/var/lib/mongodb/data/db` exist? do you have the required access rights to it?

Comment: no. it doesnt exist and idk how to make it. i am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: congratulations, your edit has made the errors less readable

Comment: that is not a programming issue - you've asked in the wrong forum - try http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "2017-02-12T14:39:18.645+0530 I STORAGE [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /var/lib/mongodb/data/db not found., terminating "   why is this happening?

Comment: `why is this happening?` why? well, because `it doesnt exist and idk how to make it`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to follow following procedure:

1. Create a dbpath: `mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb/data/db`
2. Allow required permissions: `sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/data/db/ -R`
3. Start mongodb from command line as: `mongod -dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/data/db`

Answer (score 0):

`/data/db` is the default ( i.e. with no conf file )

`/var/lib/mongodb`  is how it is configured in many distributions via the `/etc/mongodb.conf` file.

Before doing any of the other solutions see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61536226/1113082).

**Maybe your conf file is being rejected due to outdated options or format changes.**