# When running Mongodb got NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The error generated when executed `sudo mongod`   executed

```
2018-09-13T20:56:08.259+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3419 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=admin
        2018-09-13T20:56:08.260+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.7    
        2018-09-13T20:56:08.260+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 2628472127e9f1826e02c665c1d93880a204075e
        2018-09-13T20:56:08.260+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
        2018-09-13T20:56:08.260+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: 
    tcmalloc
        2018-09-13T20:56:08.260+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
        2018-09-13T20:56:08.260+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
        2018-09-13T20:56:08.260+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
        2018-09-13T20:56:08.260+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
        2018-09-13T20:56:08.260+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
        2018-09-13T20:56:08.260+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
        2018-09-13T20:56:08.312+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
        2018-09-13T20:56:08.312+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
        2018-09-13T20:56:08.312+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I'm a beginner in MEAN stack application development and stuck with this error. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

This solution solves my problem

1. Make a directory as

   sudo mkdir -p /data/db
2. That will make a directory named as db and than try to start with commands

   sudo mongod

If you get another error or problem with starting mongod, You may find problem as

> Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
>   If you find that another error than you have to kill the running process of mongod by typing to terminal as

```
ps ax | grep mongod
```

Find the mongod running port and kill the process.

```
sudo kill ps_number
```

Another way is to make a specefic port when starting mongod as

```
sudo mongod --port 27018
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cd ~
mongod
```

All you need to do above step to prevent the error.

## Don't run the mongod at different local disk location.

eg. My computer has two local disk:

1.) Local disk E: - drive : (When I run mongod on E: drive or on targeting any location on E local disk then I will get error message as)

```
Admin@DESKTOP-CJBHIMO MINGW64 /e/Full-Stack-Developer
$ mongod
...
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-22T11:33:26.675+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory E:\\data\\db\\ not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
...
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-22T11:33:26.677+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

#### {"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory E:\data\db\ not found.

2.) Local disk C: - drive : (When I run mongod on C: drive, which I recommend to use, cause, we mostly do the installation of mongodb on C: drive as per the instruction. If in your case, you installed on another drive, then run mongod on that drive's folder on hyper. Eg. as I run mongod on C:

```
Admin@DESKTOP-CJBHIMO MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ mongod

{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-22T00:52:23.840-07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/data/db/","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
...
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-22T11:34:59.300+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

#### "msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/data/db/","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}

This whole example is based on windows 10. It runs successful on root directory cause it is inside C: disk. To get inside root directory :

Comment: Please re-format your post so that it could be well understood.

Comment: Sure @kk. will format the post best in my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of make a new dir like the answers above, you can specify that you like that the mongo will run on the current or or path so just:

```
mongod --dbpath .
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

On the machine running the mongoDB server

Comment: Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use

Comment: try running `sudo killall -15 mongod` and starrting the server again

Comment: Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use

Comment: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating

Comment: Add write permission to /data/db

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any of the other solutions see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61536226/1113082).
Maybe your conf file is being rejected due to outdated options or format changes.