# Error while connecting mongodb shell

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It was working fine.But now shell is giving error while connecting. The error is

```
Thu May 9 11:03:47.710 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112 exception: connect failed
```

I reinstall it but again same error

Comment: Is the daemon running? A shot in the dark, but who knows.

Comment: Search First Post Next.. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726032/couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-1-shell-mongo-js)