# MongoDB Error couldn't connect to server

Tags: mongodb

I first execute the command:

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```

I get the prompt:

```
stop: Unknown instance: 
mongodb start/running, process 3175
```

Then,I execute the command:

```
mongo
```

I get the error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: test
Tue Oct  8 19:48:08.961 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at  src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

I don't know how I get this error.

Comment: Run `ps -ef | grep mongo` to make sure the process started and stayed up. Looks like it starts then crashes. If that's the case, check the mongo error log. (assuming you're on Linux)

Comment: Thanks,I have get the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726032/couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-1-shell-mongo-js?rq=1

Comment: Looks like your problem is solved, you have to answered your question and closed it....

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Execute the following command

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

then

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```

Comment: should be: sudo service mongod restart

Answer (score 0):

Just Execute these following lines:

1. sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
2. mongod --repair
3. sudo start mongodb
4. sudo status mongodb
5. mongo

Now you can access to your mongo terminal.