# how do I create a collection in mongoDB using an Ansible playbook?

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, ansible

I'm using Ansible to configure a Vagrant VM that, on `vagrant up`, starts mongoDB and creates a database and collection ready to receive data. Another process will write data to the mongoDB collection. Here's a snippet from the playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  user: vagrant
  sudo: True

  tasks:
    - name: install packages
      action: apt update_cache=yes pkg={{item}} state=installed
      with_items:
        - mongodb

    - service: name=mongodb state=started

    - shell: mongo mydb --eval "db.createCollection('mycollection')"
```

The playbook installs and starts the mongoDB service. However, it doesn't create the database/collection. There's something wrong with the "`- shell: mongo ...`" line. It returns:

```
TASK: [shell mongo mydb --eval "db.createCollection('mycollection')"] **** 
failed: [default] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "mongo mydb --eval\"db.createCollection('mycollection')\" ", "delta": "0:00:00.084196", "end": "2014-08-29 04:48:40.333460", "rc": 255, "start": "2014-08-29 04:48:40.249264"}
stderr: exception: connect failed
stdout: MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: mydb
Fri Aug 29 04:48:40 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
```

Can you see what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should be correct. I just tested your mongo line on a vagrant booted instance with mongo installed and it worked fine.

Can you check the mongo logs to see what it is complaining about? If you can't connect, it could be that the mongo service is binding to ipv6 addr, binding to wrong port (should be 27017), or their are some authentication issues.

After checking that, can you boot the machine, get on the shell, then execute this bit:

mongo mydb --eval "db.createCollection('mycollection')"

Does it work from the shell? (run as same user as Ansible).

Comment: Thanks @tmruss. It does work from the shell when logged in as the same user that Ansible uses. It does not work from the playbook. I'm not sure how to check the logs on the VM because it wasn't provisioned due to the error.

Comment: @AlexWoolford maybe i'm misunderstanding - if you are able to test it from the shell, you should be able to access the mongo logs?

Comment: A few other suggestions:
- Make sure you have bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 in the mongo conf file (Put there by you or ansible/provisioners)
- Some people have had luck removing a lock file, but I'm doubtful that is the issue in your case since it is a vagrant vm: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726032/

Comment: Per your the link you sent, I added "- shell: sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock" and "- shell: sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --repair" to the playbook and it worked. In the end, I found that a simple "- shell: sleep 10" had the same effect, and so ultimately I used that for its simplicity. It seems that the mongodb service wasn't ready to receive connections even though it had started and a brief delay gave it enough time to settle down and accept connections.