# mongo shell throwing error while running "show collections" command

Tags: mongodb

My mongo shell is starting without any error
`>use mydb` is also working properly (here db name is mydb)
but when i am giving show collections command, it is showing following error.

```
>show collections  
Wed Oct 15 17:38:30 uncaught exception: error: {  
  "$err" : "file /var/lib/mongodb/mydb.6 open/create failed in createPrivateMap (look in log for more information)",  
  "code" : 13636  
}
```

Here is the error log

```
17:38:22 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53178 #1
17:38:30 [conn1] ERROR: mmap private failed with out of memory. You are using a 32-bit build and probably need to upgrade to 64
17:38:30 [conn1] Assertion: 13636:file /var/lib/mongodb/mydb.6 open/create failed in createPrivateMap (look in log for more information)
17:38:30 [conn1] assertion 13636 file /var/lib/mongodb/mydb.6 open/create failed in createPrivateMap (look in log for more information) ns:mydb.system.namespaces query:{}
17:39:01 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:2 virt:90 mapped:0
```

Based on one solution given for another stackoverflow question ,[couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726032/couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-1-shell-mongo-js/16052122#16052122) , i tried same step in my case and problem was solved for time being, but the main issue is whenever i shutdown my machine and restart again i get the same error and i have to repeat same steps (as given in above link) to make mongo shell working and it ultimately lead to data loss within collections. Can anyone suggest what could be the reason , is there some problem with my mongodb installation? Please let me know if anyone had similar issue and successfully resolved it . Thanks

Comment: Hi,I have added error logs in original post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think there's two possible sources of the problem:

1. your computer doesn't have enough RAM available
2. as the log message says, you are using a 32-bit build of MongoDB and should use a 64-bit build, because you have two much data to memory map with 32-bit (> about 2.5 GB)