# Can't get mongodb to run. Tried `mongod --repair` and tried deleting lock file?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I first try to connect via `mongo`, and I get the following:

`Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:<port>  at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed`

First, I've tried the following, as per answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726032/couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-1-shell-mongo-js):

- removed the `sudo mongod.lock` file with root permission
- and tried `sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf    --repair`

I received the error `Can't specify both --journal and --repair options`.

Then, I tried just using regular `mongo --repair`, and got the following:

`file names: a list of files to run. files have to end in .js and will exit after unless --shell is specified`

What is a way around these two erorrs, or what is the way to fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: "DIDN'T WORK.".....   we're really going to need more information here to help you.   Can you please detail what errors you're running into?

Comment: I've edited the question.  Part of the problem is that I really don't want to mess anything up because this data is precious.  Even though it is backed up, it was a pain to put in collections, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By restarting the server, the problem was solved:

`service mongodb restart`

And after this, it started as normal.